# Pygame Play Sounds Blocking

Tags: pygame

i am trying to play sounds with pygame sound. My code is this:

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame
root= Tk()
pygame.init()
bass = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds\\bass.wav')
snare = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds\snare.wav')
crash = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds\crash.wav')
bass.play()
snare.play()
crash.play()
root.mainloop()
```

When i run this code all three wave files are played together.

I want to play them one after the other, and possibly have control over the time difference between each successive sounds .

What is an elegant way to do this ?

Thanks a lot for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pygame.mixer.music` module allows you to queue files to play, although I don't know of how you could specify a buffer between sounds.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.queue

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('sounds\bass.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.queue('sounds\snare.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.queue('sounds\crash.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Just be aware that `mixer.music` streams the audio, unlike the `mixer.Sound` object which will load the entire file first.

Comment: hi this code only plays the first loaded sound. do i need to init with some added parameters. i am current using pygame.init() and it plays only the first sound. The wav files are all one second long, if that is a cause of concern

Comment: Hmm.  In the docs it shows the first sound being loaded, then played, and while it's playing the other sounds are queued.  Have you tried that?

Comment: yes i tried this example as well as the one shown in pygame docs. I am still able to play only the first sound :(

Comment: Is it possible that the program exits before the additional sounds are able to be played?

Comment: I've tried it both ways with WAV files (queueing all sounds before playing, and also playing the first sound and queueing the rest while it plays) and it worked for me.  My feeling is that either the program is exiting before the second two sounds are played, or some of the files are using an unsupported codec.  Are there any error messages being printed?